# Different security for different components on Xcelsius

Tags: xcelsius

Got a dashboard with 6 different Pie charts for 6 regions and One overall aggregate pie chart combining all 6 regions. I am trying to align it somehow to the user logins, so if the section manager logs in through infoview, he will be able to see all the 7 charts, but if a Regional Manager logs in he should be able to see the overall chart and the chart for his region only, hiding the other regions. 
 The dashboard is build on top of Live Office Universe Query, based on a Universe on top of a Bex query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of tricky, but you can get the windows user with javascript or aspx. Then you can use External Interface Connection to pass the user to the .swf file.

Finally you can show and hide different components depending of the priveleges of the user.

This is the javscipt line that would let you do that using .aspx

```
 movieName.setDataSource('dataName','<%=Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1)%>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use WebI Report with CurrentUser() formula and next combine this with some kind of mapping table in Xcelsius where you assign display rights for each chart to each user.